# On the integer of the form p^a q^b closest to a given integer N

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, prime-numbers

If we give ourselves a number having only one prime factor $p$ and a given natural integer $N$, we know how to give the integer of the form $p^k$ closest (and less than) to this integer $N$ it's simple $p^{\lfloor \mathrm{log}_p(N) \rfloor}$.

I tried to generalize this problem to the following question: If we are given two distinct prime numbers $p$ and $q$, what is then the closest integer (and less than) of the form $p^a q^b$ of a given integer $N$?

The inequality $p^a q^b \le N$ leads us to:
$a + b \mathrm{log}_p(q) \le \mathrm{log}_p(N)$.Generally speaking, the equation line $y = -x \mathrm{log}_p(q) + \mathrm{log}_p(N)$ defined with the abscissa and ordinate axes a triangular region of the plane which contains the set of integers $a$ and $b$ such that $p^a q^b \le N$. It is therefore a question of finding the point with integer coordinates of this plane region which minimizes the (euclidean) distance to the line above.

**The distance**

The line intersects the x-axis at the point $- \frac{\mathrm{log}_p(N)}{\mathrm{log}_p(q)}$.

So the points with integer coordinates of this region of the plane take values ​​in the set $E =\{0, ..., \lfloor - \frac{\mathrm{log}_p(N)}{\mathrm{log} _p(q)} \rfloor \}$. For each integer $m$ in the set $E$, the point which has the abscissa $m$ which minimizes the distance to the line is the point with the ordinate : $\lfloor -m \mathrm{log}_p(q ) + \mathrm{log}_p(N) \rfloor$
The point that minimizes the distance to the line is found among the following points:
$\{(m, \lfloor -m \mathrm{log}_p(q ) + \mathrm{log}_p(N) \rfloor) | m \in E \}$

For each of these integers $m$ we can calculate the distance $d_m$ from the coordinate point $(m, \lfloor -m \mathrm{log}_p(q )+ \mathrm{log}_p(N) \rfloor) $  to the line which is miraculously worth:
$$d_m = \frac{\{ \lambda m + \gamma \}}{\sqrt{\lambda^2 + 1}}$$
Where :
$\lambda = - \mathrm{log}_p(q)$ and $\gamma = \mathrm{log}_p(N)$ and $\{x \} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ is the fractional part of $x$.

The distance $d_m$ is therefore minimal for the integer $m$ which makes the fractional part $\{ \lambda m + \gamma \}$ minimal. In other words, if $m_0$ makes the number $\{ \lambda m + \gamma\}$ minimal then $p^{m_0} q^{\lfloor \lambda m_0 + \gamma \rfloor}$ is the closest integer of the form $p^a q^b$ to $N$.

**The set $\{ \{ \lambda m + \gamma \} | m \in E \}$**

We can already consider that $\lambda$ and $\gamma$ are numbers between $0$ and $1$ because:
$$ \{ \lambda m + \gamma \} = \{ (\lfloor \lambda \rfloor + \{\lambda \}) m + \lfloor \gamma \rfloor + \{ \gamma \} \} = \{ \{\lambda \} m + \{ \gamma \} \} $$

Furthermore, we can note that $\lambda$ and $\gamma$ are irrational numbers and that the fractional part cannot be calculated easily.

Finally, we can note that if $m$ is an integer and if $ \lambda(m + 1) + \gamma < 1$ then $ \{ \lambda m + \gamma \} < \{ \lambda( m + 1) + \gamma \}$. More generally, if we take an integer $m$ and we look at the sequence $\lambda m + \gamma$, $\lambda(m + 1) + \gamma$, ..., $\lambda(m + n ) + \gamma$ such that $\lambda( m + n) + \gamma < 1$ then $ \lambda m + \gamma $ will be the minimum of this sequence. To find the minimum of the set, it is enough to look at the numbers $\lambda m + \gamma$ which just exceed one unit.

We can therefore construct the following subsequence $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$:

$$ u_0 = \{ \lambda \times 0 + \gamma \} = \{ \gamma \} = \gamma $$

Then if we take a generic term from the sequence: $u_n$, we look for $u_{n + 1}$ such that $u_{n + 1} = \{ \lambda k + u_n \}$ where $k$ is the integer such that $\lambda k + u_n$ just exceeds $1$. In other words: $k = \lfloor \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \rfloor + 1$. In the end we therefore have:

$$u_{n + 1} = \{ \lambda \left( 1 + \lfloor \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \rfloor \right) + u_n \} $$

If we write that $v(n) = \{ \lambda m + \gamma \}$ then we have that $u_n$ is its subsequence defined by induction by:
$$ u _0 = \gamma = v(0)$$
$$ u_n = v \left( \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \left( 1 + \lfloor \frac{1 - u_k}{\lambda} \rfloor \right) \right) $$

**The subsequence $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$**

*Lemma 1*

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, u_{n + 1} = \lambda \left( 1 - \{ \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \} \right) $$

*Proof*

$$u_{n + 1} = \{ \lambda \left( 1 + \lfloor \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \rfloor \right) + u_n \} $$
$$ u_{n + 1} = \lambda \left( 1 + \lfloor \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \rfloor \right) + u_n - \lfloor \lambda \left( 1 + \lfloor \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \rfloor \right) + u_n \rfloor $$

But we defined $1 + \lfloor \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \rfloor$ as the smallest integer such that $\lambda \left( 1 + \lfloor \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \rfloor \right) + u_n $ is greater than 1. So :

$$\lfloor \lambda \left( 1 + \lfloor \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \rfloor \right) + u_n \rfloor = 1$$

$$ u_{n + 1} = \lambda \left( 1 + \left(  \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} - \{ \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \} \right) \right) + u_n - 1 $$
$$u_{n + 1} = \lambda \left( 1 - \{ \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \} \right) $$
*Lemma 2*

$$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, u_n \le \lambda $$

*Proof*

Deduce by lemma 1

*Lemma 3*

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, u_{n + 1} - u_n = \lambda \left( 1 + \lfloor \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \rfloor \right) - 1$$

*Proof*

$$ u_{n + 1} = \lambda \left( 1 + \left(  \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} - \{ \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \} \right) \right) + u_n - 1 $$
$$ u_{n + 1} - u_n = \lambda \left( 1 + \left(  \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} - \{ \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \} \right) \right) - 1 $$

*Lemma 4*

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$$ u_n \le \lambda \{ \frac{1}{\lambda} \} \Leftrightarrow \lfloor \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{1}{\lambda} \rfloor $$
$$ u_n > \lambda \{ \frac{1}{\lambda} \} \Leftrightarrow \lfloor \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{1}{\lambda} \rfloor -1 $$

*Proof*

We know that $\frac{u_n}{\lambda} \le 1$

$$ \lfloor \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{1}{\lambda} \rfloor \Leftrightarrow \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \ge \lfloor \frac{1}{\lambda} \rfloor  $$
$$ \lfloor \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{1}{\lambda} \rfloor \Leftrightarrow u_n \le \lambda \{ \frac{1}{\lambda} \} $$

And :

$$ \lfloor \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{1}{\lambda} \rfloor -1 \Leftrightarrow \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} < \lfloor \frac{1}{\lambda} \rfloor$$
$$ \lfloor \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{1}{\lambda} \rfloor -1 \Leftrightarrow u_n > \lambda \{\frac{1}{\lambda} \}$$

*Lemma 5*

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

$$ u_n \le \lambda \{ \frac{1}{\lambda} \} \Rightarrow u_{n + 1} > u_n$$
$$ u_n > \lambda \{ \frac{1}{\lambda} \} \Rightarrow u_{n + 1} \le u_n$$

*Proof*

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, u_{n + 1} - u_n = \lambda \left( 1 + \lfloor \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \rfloor \right) - 1$$

If $u_n \le \lambda \{ \frac{1}{\lambda} \}$, $\lfloor \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{1}{\lambda} \rfloor$, then:

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, u_{n + 1} - u_n = \lambda \left( 1 + \lfloor \frac{1}{\lambda} \rfloor \right) - 1$$

$$\frac{1}{\lambda} < \lfloor \frac{1}{\lambda} \rfloor + 1$$
$$u_{n + 1} > u_n$$

If $u_n > \lambda \{ \frac{1}{\lambda} \}$ then $u_{n+1} \le u_n$$ similarly.

Finally we get the following result :

$$ u_n \le \lambda \{ \frac{1}{\lambda} \} \Rightarrow u_{n + 1} = u_n + \lambda \left(1 - \{ \frac{1}{\lambda} \} \right) $$
$$ u_n > \lambda \{ \frac{1}{\lambda} \} \Rightarrow u_{n + 1} = u_n - \lambda \{ \frac{1}{\lambda} \} $$

**Question**

If we note $\phi_u(N)$ the smallest interger such that :
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\phi_u (N)-1} \left(1 + \lfloor \frac{1 - u_n}{\lambda} \rfloor \right) > \lfloor - \frac{\mathrm{log}_p(N)}{\mathrm{log} _p(q)} \rfloor $$

We have to find the minimum of the subsequence $(u_n)$ for $n \in \{0, ..., \phi_u (N) - 1 \}$.
Any help to find this minimum ?

Comment: If N is perfect power or has small radical this is related to the abc conjecture.

Comment: Once you approximate the logarithms with enough precision this is an ILP instance, perhaps you can take a look at algorithms for it.

Comment: Given $p,q,N$ we're trying to find $a,b$ to minimize the positive number $X=\log N-a\log p-b\log q$. We have a bound on, say, $a$ (given by $\log N/\log p$), so we can just find the optimal $b$ for each feasible value of $a$, and then select the one that minimizes $X$. This should be pretty efficient for reasonable sizes of the givens. I don't hold out much hope for any kind of formula to give an answer, as a small change in $N$ can force a large change in $a$ and $b$.